# Aurelia: Update the custom element on changes to the bound object

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom element called `summary-bar` with `summary` property:

```
export class SummaryBarCustomElement {
    @bindable summary;
    ---
```

In another component `test-website`, I uses the `summary-bar` element and bind its data as below:

```
<summary-bar summary.bind="testWebsiteSummary"></summary-bar>
```

And here `testWebsiteSummary` is defined in the `test-website.js` ViewModel:

```
export class TestWebsiteCustomElement {

    testWebsiteSummary = {
        passed_result_count: 0,
        failed_result_count: 0,
        incomplete_result_count: 0,
        unknown_result_count: 0
    }
    ---
```

There are several functions in TestWebsiteCustomElement class that modify the values of `testWebsiteSummary.passed_result_count`, `testWebsiteSummary.failed_result_count`, `testWebsiteSummary.incomplete_result_count` and `testWebsiteSummary.unknown_result_count`. However, the `summary-bar` element is not reloaded with the new values of `testWebsiteSummary`. Is there a way to achieve that? What I mean is every time the properties of `testWebsiteSummary` is updated, is it possible to update the `summary-bar` with the new values? Thank you.

Example of a function which changes the properties:

```
 changeWebsiteSummary(status) {
    switch (status) {
        case "SUCCESS":
        this.testWebsiteSummary.passed_result_count++;
        this.testWebsiteSummary.incomplete_result_count--;
        break;
        case "INCOMPLETE":
        this.testWebsiteSummary.incomplete_result_count++;
        this.testWebsiteSummary.passed_result_count--;
        break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you bind an object into your Custom Element it will update its values automatically. Whenever your TestWebsiteCustomElement changes any of the properties in testWebsiteSummary, those changes will be automatically reflected in your SummaryBarCustomElement. That is, if you are for example displaying testWebsiteSummary.passed_result_count in the SummaryBarCustomElement view, then it will be automatically updated in the ui.

Now, if what you want is to know when those changes occur to do something else, then you need to use a propertyObserver.

Aurelia by default support adding methods such as summaryChanged(newValue, oldValue) to custom elements. This works just fine for primitive values, but for Objects (or arrays) this method will not be triggered if any of the internal properties changes, only if the object itself has been reassigned.

To work around this you can use the binding engine to observe specific properties inside your summary object. Here is what it would look like:

```
import {bindable, BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class SummaryBarCustomElement {
  @bindable summary;

  constructor(bindingEngine){
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  bind(){
    this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this.summary, 'passed_result_count')
      .subscribe(newValue, oldValue => this.passedResultCountChanged(newValue, oldValue))
  }

  detached(){
    this.subscription.dispose();
  }

  passedResultCountChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I expected it works that way too, but when any of the testWebsiteSummary's properties changes, the ui was not updated.

Comment: That is very weird, could you please provide a plunker so we can see you exact example?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code section that updated the testWebsiteSummary's properties. Even that code ran, the ui did not get updated.

Comment: How do you know it is not being updated? Are you displaying the properties in your Custom Element  view?

Comment: The summary bar component shows the passed_result_count, incomplete_result_count, but it was not updated

Comment: Yeah it is very weird, unfortunately without a complete example not sure I can help you.

Comment: I think I know why. The statement above `The summary bar component shows the passed_result_count, incomplete_result_count` is not really true. I have an intermediate function that compute percentages based on the  passed_result_count, incomplete_result_count, etc. One idea to use property observer like you mentioned and call that function again on property changed. How do I create observer on multiple properties?

Comment: I think you will have to call `this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver` once for each property you want to observe. I found some implementations in the internet that created a util class that would allow you to listen to multiple properties easily, of course  they are just doing exactly what I'm suggesting, it is just easier for the caller.

Comment: Thanks for that. I still cannot make it work with that approach. In the `passedResultCountChanged`, I only have access to the oldValue and newValue and cannot modify the summary in any way.

Comment: You have access to the whole thing, just call `this.summary` directly, at that point your summary object will have the updated values

Comment: When i try to call `this.summary` in `passedResultCountChanged`, this is the error: `aurelia-task-queue.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined`

Comment: I think I know why, we are moving out of the Model-View scope. I have updated the original answer with the new code, we basically need to use an arrow function so we can remain in the View-Model scope: `.subscribe(newValue, oldValue => this.passedResultCountChanged(newValue, oldValue))`

Comment: Anyway, I figured it out. As I mentioned, because I do not use the property from `this.summary` directly, I created a getter called `get summaryResult()` and return an intermediate object which is used in the summary-bar component. In this way, whenever a property of summary object is updated, the `get summaryResult()` get called and the bar is updated.

Comment: That is ok, but be aware that this will resort to dirty checking.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much for your help. I will try your above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `signal` binding behaviour

```
<summary-bar summary.bind="testWebsiteSummary & signal:'your-signal'"></summary-bar>
```

And the class:

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';
export class TestWebsiteCustomElement {

    constructor(signaler: BindingSignaler) {
      this.signaler = signaler;
    }

    functionThatChangesValues(){
      this.signaler.signal('your-signal');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the correct way. But still does not work for me after changing. Does it work with object or only with primitive data?

Comment: Hmm, maybe my answer is not the one you are looking for. This code should force Aurelia to check the binding, and i thought it should work with objects too

Comment: I thunk u will get this working by raising an event with EventAggregator (including changed testWebsiteSummary) in TestWebsiteCustomElement, subscribing for it in SummaryBarCustomElement and chnaging the values in the child view. But I'm not sure that's the right path. I have no idea btw, why your code is not working. It looks like the proper way of doing it.